# Links in e-mail are opened by someone else (Django)

Tags: django, apache, amazon-ec2, smtp

I'm running Django on an Apache server on Ubuntu and the activation of a new account via a link in an e-mail fails sometimes. I've checked my access logs and I can see that the activation link is opened by an EC2 server (whois lookup gives an AWS resource, IP is not the public IP of my own server). Any ideas who/what this could be? I have TLS enabled in settings.py for sending emails: EMAIL_USE_TLS = True.

So the reason for failing the activiation is because the link is already openend, but I'm worried what happens there. I've seen this happening 3 times with completely different user agents for 3 completely different account-activations but from the same IP address.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came to my mind is that maybe an e-mail client is opening the links to generate a preview? Like, to show a screenshot when the user hovers the link.

Why do you make links usable once? You can use a token that is valid until the account is actually activated (and disable the link if the account is not activated for a certain amount of time).

Comment: It's 3 times the same IP address for very different accounts so I think the problem is closer to me instead of the user. And the default Django implementation validates the activation token only once, so people are getting an error now even though they can login. I would like to really validate the e-mail address so I want the people to open my activation URL instead of some client/robot...

Comment: How about requiring some user interaction after loading the page? Like "Click here to activate your account" button?